# Send a div through a form and with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

How can I send a contenteditable div through a form with jQuery?
I tried to create an input hidden and with jQuery put the content of the div in the input, but it does not work. Do I have anything wrong? is there any easier way?

jQUERY:

```
$(function(){
     $("#boto").click(function(event){  
       $("#transport").val() = $("#input").innerHTML;
     });
})
```

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div id="input" contenteditable="true"> </div>
    <input type='hidden' id="transport" name='transport' /> <br/> 
    <input type='submit' id="boto" value='submit' /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$(function(){
     $("#boto").click(function(event){  
       $("#transport").val($("#input").html());
    //or
        $("#transport").val($("#input").text());
     });
})
```

Comment: `innerhtml` is a javascript function but when you gets the object of element with `jquery` then you have to use jquery's function like `.html(), .text()`

Comment: Is there any difference between .html() and .text() ?

Answer (score 1):

To set a value use:

```
$("#transport").val($("#input").text());
```

and not:

```
$("#transport").val() = $("#input").innerHTML;
```